# How to split unequal columns in R

Tags: r, database-design, split, tapply

I have a data set that should contain 14 columns, but when I read it into R it presents as two columns, with the latter columns reading in as one, and are all separated by "."

I read in using:

> dat <- read.table ("/data/GER.female.RAWMACH", header = F, sep = "\t")

Below I have provided the output:

> head (dat)

V1
TRAIT
CASE
CASE
CASE
CASE
CASE
CASE

V2
MARKER..........ALLELES..FREQ1....RSQR...EFFECT1..OR......STDERR..WALDCHISQ.PVALUE.....LRCHISQ.LRPVAL.NCASES.NCONTROLS
rs7      T A      .9104   .0001   -3.944   0.019   19.634  0.0403 0.8408     0.0403  0.8409    260       446

rs6      A C      .9114   .0002   -2.552   0.078   14.349  0.0316    0.8589     0.0316  0.8589  260       446

rs9    C T      .8444   .0001    2.772   15.985  15.076 
 0.0338    0.8541     0.0338  0.8542    260       446

rs5    G A      .9164   .0001   -3.683   0.025   18.039  0.0417    0.8382     0.0417 
 0.8383    260       446

rs2       T C      .5168   .0001   -2.466   0.085   10.811  0.0520    0.8195     0.0520  0.8196    260       446

rs1        T G      .8229   .0002   -1.727   0.178   12.241  0.0199   0.8878     0.0199  0.8878    260       446

I have tried a few things (rewriting the table, colsplit) with no success. What am I missing?

I appreciate any suggestions you may have!

Comment: You should show the code you're using to read the data, and also what the original data looks like, paying closer attention to formatting, so it's readable.

Comment: Okay, thanks Joran. I'm new to the site, I just found the text editor toolbar that let's you post code without loosing the formatting. Very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You thought you had a tab separated file, but it wasn't. You also DO have a header. Just use the default white-space separator by dropping the `sep="\t"` and setting `header=TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks! The issue I'm having now is that the actual data is tab separated (and also has some missing values), it's just the header line that is separated by "." So, if I removed sep="\t" from the code, I get an error in scan: Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 233669 did not have 15 elements.

Comment: You probably should read the first line in with `readLines`, split it up as appropriate and then use `skip=1` with  `input <- read.table` and then `names(input) <-` ... the processed header vector.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with readLines, that's a good resource. Thanks again! I ended up solving my problem with : dat <- read.delim(file="/data/GER.female.RawMach2", header =F, sep="")

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without more information, but I'm pretty confident that the best way to solve this will be through loading the table properly in the first place. Unless the actual structure of the data that you're loading is in the form that you're getting, you're loading it wrong; look at the documentation for `read.table` and related methods, in particular the `sep` and `header` arguments. I'm guessing this will clear up your issue with the data import without requiring after-the-fact cleanup.